# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>>' in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

I have a type issue with a data I get from Firebase Functions.

```dart
  @override
  Future<RawCollection> list({required RawDocument data}) async {
    loggy.debug('Listing deck data...');

    final result = await _firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable('listDeck')(data);
    return result.data;
  }
```

`RawCollection` and `RawDocument` are simple type aliases for convenience defined like this:

```dart
typedef RawDocument = Map<String, dynamic>;
typedef RawCollection = Iterable<RawDocument>;
```

However, this code fails saying:

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
```

However, I'm sure `result.data` is a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` in this case. The test data I get from Firebase Functions is as below:

```json
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-12-15T12:26:12.258Z",
    "targetLang": "ae",
    "sourceLang": "ak",
    "cardCount": 0,
    "id": "wiXvWfxjgMBn3nAC9uQg",
    "label": "bar",
    "userId": "fwOBxD0UoA6KBxCWauVB2cM7PL9n",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-15T12:26:12.258Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-12-15T11:48:46.046Z",
    "targetLang": "an",
    "sourceLang": "sq",
    "cardCount": 0,
    "id": "EC21qguc1sXME82jysJQ",
    "label": "foo",
    "userId": "fwOBxD0UoA6KBxCWauVB2cM7PL9n",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-15T11:48:46.046Z"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2022-12-15T15:39:28.297377",
    "targetLang": "ar",
    "sourceLang": "sq",
    "cardCount": 0,
    "id": "oWnkt9NcFStQxnU2x893",
    "label": "que",
    "userId": "fwOBxD0UoA6KBxCWauVB2cM7PL9n",
    "updatedAt": "2022-12-15T12:39:39.714Z"
  }
]
```

So, it should be a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`.

Why is the type of response `List<Object?>` instead of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`?

Thanks in advance.

### Troubleshooting

#### `.whereType`

So, I thought filtering it with `.whereType` would work:

```dart
  @override
  Future<RawCollection> list({required RawDocument data}) async {
    loggy.debug('Listing deck data...');

    final result = await _firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable('listDeck')(data);
    final resData = result.data.whereType<RawDocument>(); // this is empty
    return resData;
  }
```

However, this time, the strange thing is `resData` is empty. I still get the sample data I've given above, but for some strange reason, it doesn't filter by that.

I've also tried with `final RawCollection resData = result.data.whereType<RawDocument>();`, but this also does not work.

Converting with `toList()` also returns empty.

---

## Environment

Flutter Doctor (-v):

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on Fedora Linux 36 (KDE Plasma) 6.1.7-100.fc36.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /home/erayerdin/.local/lib/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (6 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /home/erayerdin/.sdks/android/
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/erayerdin/.sdks/android
    • Java binary at: /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/125/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 14.0.5 (Fedora 14.0.5-2.fc36)
    • cmake version 3.25.1
    • ninja version 1.10.2
    • pkg-config version 1.8.0

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /var/lib/snapd/snap/android-studio/125/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code
    • VS Code at /snap/code/current
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • Linux (desktop)              • linux         • linux-x64      • Fedora Linux 36 (KDE Plasma) 6.1.7-100.fc36.x86_64
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: It appears like your `result.data` is an `Iterable<Map>` and not an `Iterable<Map<String,dynamic>>`. Also most of the times when JSON get parsed, it simply returns a `Map`(aka `Map<dynamic,dynamic>`) instead of `Map<String,dynamic>`, in Flutter. So I believe your code should be something like this:

`typedef RawDocument = Map;`

Comment: @AyanSengupta can we also fix this with `final resData = result.data as List<RawDocument>;`  instead of `final resData = result.data.whereType<RawDocument>();` will work ?

Comment: @RohitKharche | I've tried syntactic casting like you've done here, or [cast](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html) method. None of them worked but, at least, @AyanSengupta is right on point that Firebase Functions returns `List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>`. I will reply as answer if I can find the solution.

Comment: @ErayErdin yeah I think @Ayan Sengupta suggestion will work. Although to make it more specific we can also use `Map<String, dynamic>` as the type for `RawDocument`. It will still need `typedef RawDocument = Map<String, dynamic>;` However, it's also possible to create a custom class or a `typedef` that includes the specific fields you expect to find in the JSON data, this will give you a more type-safe and readable code.

Comment: @RohitKharche casting with `as` or `cast()` will only work if the target type you are casting to matches the actual type. For example, if you have a `List<Object>`/`List<dynamic>` and you definitely know that each item in that `List` is actually a `String`, you can use `cast<String>()` right away. But by no means a `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` is "cast"able to `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Comment: This is because, you can consider generics as two completely separate classes in terms of the compiler/runtime. So `Map<dynamic,dynamic>` = Map_dynamic_dynamic and `Map<String,dynamic>` = Map_String_dynamic for the compiler/runtime, evidently not "cast"able to each other. I really wish the dart compiler would have picked these issues during compile time instead of reporting them at runtime. But till now `cast()` fully depends on the `runtimeType` of an object and thus could not be pointed out so far during compilation.

Comment: @ErayErdin in the context of the above, if you really wanna continue using `typedef RawDocument = Map<String,dynamic>;`, you need to individually `cast()` each element in your list, instead of casting the list itself. So you can also use `return result.data.map((e) => e.cast<String,dynamic>());` instead of simply returning `result.data;`

Comment: @AyanSengupta | In that case, I get `'MappedListIterable<Object?, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>>'` for some reason.

Comment: Hmm I haven't tried it myself until now. So I created this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4872b0b0611a38f2036d43fdf40c2575) to mimic your scenario and it appears like the casting absolutely works for me without any glitch. Surprisingly, the runtime type after casting completely differs from yours and can't say much until I know how it has been coded on your end.

Comment: Is it possible that your `result.data` itself returns a `List<Future>`s?

Comment: That `result.data` containing `List<Future>` would be quite strange, because it comes from the response of Firebase Functions endpoint. Let me try this as well and see what happens. I will inform you about it.